# Install Ubuntu without deleting home directory from previous Install

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I had installed Fedora last year, now wanting to switch back to Ubuntu. But how do I install Ubuntu without removing all the files from my home directory from the previous Fedora install?

I've tried searching all over Google and I can't find anything. Any help?

Comment: It's only possible if your home dir is located on a separate partition. In this case you simply chose a custom-based partitioning in the installer, and instead of removing home you chose it as a partition to be mounted at `/home` dir. However, if your home partition is on the same partition as everything else, I'm afraid you're out of luck. I mean, you can of course use another disk *(or even partition for that matter)* to copy all your data there, but no automation on the installer's side.

Comment: @Hi-Angel that isn't true...   You can re-install Ubuntu Desktop systems (inc. *flavors*) even if on a single partition without losing any configs, having *manually installed* packages re-install automatically, an option that `ubiquity` used to offer via "Repair installation" decade+ ago, but is still available & triggered by the lack of format.

Comment: I have a system that contained Fedora & OpenSuSE and is now two versions of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu Desktop installers `ubiquity` & `calamares` (`calamares` is used by two flavors) can trigger this install if you use "*Manual Partitioning*" (or "*Something else*") and don't format, which causes your packages to be noted; system directories erased; new system installed, then *manually installed* package get installed too (IF internet is available & available in new release) without any change to $HOME be it on same partition or different. You're then asked to reboot

Comment: I'll provide this link (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) which covers Lubuntu QA (*Quality Assurance*) testcases; the install method I'm suggesting (*prior comment*) is called "*Install using existing partition*" (I prefer thinking of it as "*Upgrade via re-install*" as it's faster than *release-upgrade*).  It's what I'd use, and is mentioned on this site in 30+ threads but lower upvoted answers are harder to find sorry so I'm not looking  (*mostly mentioned in comments like this as I rarely find the answers*)

Comment: FYI: I mention automatic restoration of packages; that assumes a *deb* based system, as you're coming from an *rpm* based system you'll get no benefit from that so don't try (*or really expect all your added RPM/flatpak/appimage* packages to be auto-reinstalled).  You didn't specify if you're asking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop **or** Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, my comments assume desktop thus a `ubiquity` install, but you should be clear with details.  Of course backup everything first; as it's easy to make a mistake!

Comment: Below is something I wrote a few years ago about copying home to a flash drive. You can copy it back to your computer as you wish. I have not tried this with Ubuntu/Fedora.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing to another distro: can the -home partition be kept?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41079/changing-to-another-distro-can-the-home-partition-be-kept)

Answer (score 0):

**Copy home to Portable USB drive**

Format flash drive to ext4.

As root use Grsync to copy home/{username} from internal drive to the flash drive. Preserving owner, permissions and group works for me.

[image]

Copy or write down UUID of the new partition.

Edit /etc/fstab on the internal drive to add the /home UUID:

```
UUID={UUID from above} /home   ext4    defaults        0       0
```

It might be a good idea to use an encrypted home when traveling.

Thanks to ubfan1 for hint